# C# how to enable button from another class

Tags: c#, forms, button

I have a form1, there's a "download" button, and a "next" button. By default, the "next" button is disabled. When I click "download" button, I will call a method from download.cs, different from form1.cs. After downloading, I want the "next" button to be enabled, so in download.cs, after receiving all files, I put

> form1.btnNext.Enabled = true;

But it doesn't work. I also put this in form1.cs

> public void enableButton(bool enabled)
>
> {
>      btnNext.Enabled = enabled;
>   }

and in download.cs I put:

> private form1 form1;
>   ...
>
> form1.enableButton(true);

but it doesn't work either. Could any1 show me where I'm wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error or does nothing happen at all? did you set a breakpoint to see if the code actually got called?

Comment: Can you add the code that creates the variable "form1"?

Comment: Is your download done on a different thread ?

Comment: An unrelated suggestion would be to name your variables/classes better. Anything called form1 is always bad news, but having a class called form1 and then creating an instance of it also called form1 seems like a good way to create confusion :)

Comment: sorry for being a little vague. It doesn't work means the button isn't enabled after downloading. I used "form1" name just for easy typing but I do name my class. And yes, my download is done on another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are freezing your UI while download than

1- Define a event in your Downloader class

```
    public delegate void EnableUI(bool shdEnable);

    public event EnableUI MakeUIEnabled;
```

2- Hook this event in your form1 class , i assume that you are creating an object of download class in the download button or it is created at class level , lets say this object as customDownloader

```
   customDownloader.MakeUIEnabled+=new EnableUI(EnableUIControls);
```

3- Define a event hander in form1 class as shown below.

```
  public void EnableUIControls(bool shdEnable)
    {
        btnNext.Enabled = shdEnable;

    }
```

4- Let's sya that there is a downloadfile() method in download.cs file so when your download is completed than raise this event.

```
      public void DownLoadFile()
      {
          if(MakeUIEnabled!=null)
             MakeUIEnabled(true);

      }
```

tha's it

Comment: yes, this is it. It works fine for me. But now I think again it should be better a small form or a dialog pop up indicate that files are being downloaded... But I guess that's for later, for now I should try to complete my app first then improvement later. Thanks again, ur code helped me a bunch, also cleared up some cloud in my head about threading and delegate/event handle.

Answer (score 2):

Your question needs some more information to be sure, but I'm guessing that the instance of `form1` in your downloader class is not the same as the instance that's shown on your screen.

If your downloader should be able to call back to the form that started it up, the easiest way would be to pass a reference to that form along to the downloader class.

Answer (score 0):

I remember facing something like this , and you may try to make your (next) buttonpublic instead of private , but this is not a very adorable approach ,but I guess if you do hat then your first suggestion will work.

and if it doesn't you can try doing this :

Form1 myForm = new Form1;
myform.nxtButton.enabled = true;

it will definitely work

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add that I already changed the property of the button to public in form1.designer.cs, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass through a reference to the Button to the new class.  So when you call the method from download.cs, pass the name of the button through as a parameter and then you can use it within the new class as you would any other reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via a Callback. So in your Download.cs, you have something like this:

```
public delegate void EnableNextCallback (bool enable);

public static void Download(EnableNextCallback n) {
   // stuff
   // when you're done
   n(true);
}
```

That way, you can pass your EnableButton method to your download method.

Comment: thanks, this answer is the same as Saurabh's and I changed some place in the code and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference to `Form1` within `Form2`. Is `Form2` a dialog window, MDI child window,  etc.? Is `Form1` set as parent window? Does `Form1` open `Form2`?

If `Form1` does in fact open `Form2`, you can set the owner property to have a reference to `Form1` from within `Form2`. Also, ensure that `button10` in `Form1` is set to PUBLIC (it's private by default).

Within `Form1`, you'll have code like this:

```
Form2 MyForm2 = new MyForm2();

MyForm2.Owner = this; // "this" being Form1

MyForm2.Show();
```

In `Form2`, whenever you want to access `button10` on `Form1`, do this:

```
(this.Owner as Form1).button10.Enabled = false;
```